# How to update already run database migration files using Grails DBMigration plugin?

Tags: grails, database-migration, liquibase

I have migration file named `test-plugin-migration-1.2.groovy` which nedds to be only renamed as migrations listed in it are already run and some other custom migrations.

`test-plugin-migration-1.2.groovy` - > `test-plugin-migration-1-2.groovy`

I tried adding a custom migration for `DATABASECHANGELOG` table in new file named `rename-migration.groovy`

**rename-migration.groovy**

```
changeSet(author: "Laxmi Salunkhe", id: "12345-1") {
    grailsChange {
        change {
            sql.execute("""update DATABASECHANGELOG set 
                filename='test-plugin-migration-1-2.groovy' where
                filename='test-plugin-migration-1.2.groovy'""")
        }
    }
}
```

**changelog.groovy**

```
databaseChangeLog = {

    // Some Old Migrations

    include file: 'rename-migration.groovy'

    // Previously it was test-plugin-migration-1.2.groovy
    include file: 'test-plugin-migration-1-2.groovy' 

    include file: 'new-plugin-migration.groovy'
}
```

It still runs renamed file migrations again.

After going through `liquibase` documentation for [update](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html), It explains

`Liquibase executes the databaseChangeLog, it reads the changeSets in order and, for each one, checks the “databasechangelog” table to see if the combination of id/author/filepath has been run.`

What should I do to avoid renamed files change set getting applied on database?

Comment: Migration files are not intended to be renamed. Once they are created they should stay that way. What problem are you trying to solve by renaming them? Also, the DATABASECHANGELOG table is not intended to be modified directly - it is there to keep track of which changes from the changelog file have been applied to any given database instance.

Comment: I had just upgraded my app Grails version from 2.4.x to 2.5.0. And sue to invalid migration file names I come across runtime exception. To resolve it I have to rename those invalid files. I figured out solution, added below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out workaround for this problem. I have added one groovy script  `rename-file.groovy` which rename my invalid file names in `DATABASECHANGELOG` table and then migration run's sucessfully.

**rename-file.groovy**

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)
@Grab(group = "mysql", module = "mysql-connector-java", version = "5.1.29")

// Get instance of MYSQL database of old system
Sql sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/causecode", "root", "sql", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")

String oldFileName = "test-plugin-migration-1.2"
String newFileName = oldFileName.replace('.', '_') + '.groovy'
oldFileName = oldFileName + '.groovy'
String query = """
    Update DATABASECHANGELOG
    set filename = "$newFileName", MD5SUM = null
    where filename = "$oldFileName"
"""
sql.executeUpdate query


// Close the connections
sql.close()
```

and then run migration against database.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not making any changes to existing changesets, you can use command `dbm-changelog-sync` it will mark all changesets as executed so when you run-app again, your changelogs will not execute again and will be treated as they are already applied

See [dbm-changelog-sync](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/ref/Maintenance%20Scripts/dbm-changelog-sync.html)

Comment: this command can not be used as I want to rename my migration file names and also add some new migrations files. Please check I have updated my question.

Comment: You can first rename migration files and then dbm-changelog-sync and then add new migration file, when your app run next time, new migration will apply.